# Which is more efficient, Geography vs. float type in SQL Server for selecting/inserting locations?

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, processing-efficiency, sqlgeography

What is the performance impact in storing a location as a Geography type vs. simply saving the longitude and latitude as one float each?

Answer (score 2):

I ran the following test, always saving the coordinate 1,2.  This is to avoid the cost of string handling to convert the coordinates to strings, in order to use the function DECLARE @location geography = geography::Point( '1', '2', 4326 );  (which at the time of writing is the most efficient method to get a Geography type from a coordinate).

```
CREATE TABLE GeogXYtable ( GeogXYID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), GeogXY Geography );

 DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 100000) 
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @location geography = geography::Point( '1', '2', 4326 );
   INSERT INTO GeogXYtable ( GeogXY ) VALUES (@location);
   SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
```

The above loop takes 59s to run. (The SQL Server instance isn't doing anything else, and the results are the same on rerunning).

Compare this to saving the coordinate as two separate floats:

```
CREATE TABLE floatXYtable ( GeogXYID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), X float, Y float );

 DECLARE @i int = 0;
 WHILE (@i < 100000) 
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO floatXYtable ( X, Y ) VALUES ( 1, 2 );
   SET @i = @i + 1;
 END
```

The above loop takes 38s to run.

Conclusion:  saving points as Geography types is 55% slower than saving them as floats.

Comment: After five runs, my benchmark for the above shows 21s vs 17.5s, for ~16% slower. I'm running SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Summing the values in the two tables (after increasing the amount of data tenfold) has a much bigger difference - about 0.25s vs 6s for floats vs geography (floats being about 24x faster). Reading all of the actual data leads to a difference of 12s vs 19s, which is about 36% slower, most of the difference in decoding getting lost in the cost of actually sending the data.

Comment: If writing is your only concern, serializing a CLR object is going to take longer. But if you're looking to query the data for things like "select things near this other thing" or "select things that are in a certain area" the geography datatype will pay dividends. Why? Step 1 in your "store it as floats" is to do some gross trigonometry. And you get to do it for every point in your table because there's no way to index it.

Comment: @Ben, that's a separate discussion.  (But I've found that in many cases it's actually faster finding points in a radius by indexing the X and Y float fields than it is to do a spatial geometry query if there is an index on the Geography column).   But that isn't what this post is about.